# Change MFMailComposeViewController's UINavigationBar color in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, tintcolor

I am trying to update my app for `iOS7`, however I am unable to set the colour of the `UINavigationBar` at the top of the screen. I have tried the classic approach...

```
[mailer.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor darkGreyColour]];
```

...however it didn't work. I have also tried calling `setBarTintColor` instead, however that didn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know if its possible to set the colour and if so how?

Comment: Which do you mean? Toolbar or navigation bar? You are mixing both terms.

Comment: Sorry for confusion - I meant the navigation bar displayed at the top of the screen.

Comment: FYI, from [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html): _Setting the tintColor property by using the appearance proxy APIs is not supported in iOS 7._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had your same problem when updating my application for iOS 7.
I solved using this line of code (if you use images):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:@"myImage" forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

or this one if you are not using images:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

I placed then in **AppDelegate**, just before returning `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the tint in storyboard. Its in 'view' sub section when you select navigation bar in IB.